# Generate non-decimal unique id in asterisk

Tags: centos, asterisk, voip, uniqueidentifier, ivr

I want a unique id for a particular call in asterisk currently I am using `${CDR(uniqueid)}` which gives me a decimal value like `12344.4321` .
My problem is that I want a non-decimal value cause I am using this id on various places its causing some issue.

Is there a variable from which I can get a non-decimal unique id for each calls in asterisk dialplan?

Answer (score -1):

You can use MD5 or HEX function and convert decimal to hex string.

You  also can just add some pre-defined string to decimal value

```
NONDEC${CDR(uniqueid)}
```

Comment: but `NONDEC${CDR(uniqueid)}` wont remove the decimal does it? It would give something like `NONDEC1234.4321`

Comment: yep. if your "remove decimal" mean remove decimal point, use FILTER function.

Comment: is there a function to generate alphanumeric unique string?